# How to have dual license software (open + closed)

Tags: licensing

I have some closed-source code (written by me) that I'd like to keep for myself.
However I'd like to use some of that code in an open source project - which would also be written exclusively by me, but posted somewhere for anyone to use.

How can I accomplish something like this:

1. release open source version of code, which is free for anyone to
   change, and keep or give back (I believe this is zlib license)
2. at the same time I'd like to have a version of the code for
   myself,
       and be able to incorporate any code changes from #1 (if someone
       decides to fix up any code I release)

Is this as simple as having two code-trees, with different licenses attached to both? One zlib license, and one my own license?

Note, I'm a bit biased to using zlib license as it is short, and I believe I understand it and agree it is appropriate (I don't mind if someone uses code for commercial purpose).

Comment: This will not nesseicarly answer your question, but it discusses the dangers of having to go from open to closed. And since you'll be having both, take a look, it's a small read: [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/135450/taking-an-open-source-project-to-closed-source)

Comment: The internet at large isn't the right place to ask for legal advice such as this.

Comment: From a purely practical point of view, it may well make more sense to have a single code base, suitably modularized so you can link in your own closed-source plug-ins / extensions / what have you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part indeed requires two code trees. If you're using a distributed SCM, like git, mercurial or bazaar, then it wouldn't be too complicated:

1. One repo is public, open source, let's call it `open-foobar`
2. One repo is private, closed source, let's call it `enterprise-foobar`
3. In my opinion, it would be better to have the open repository as the *main* repository (upstream), which the private one *forks* and extends, but it depends on how much code do you want to keep private. If most of your commits will go into the private project, then it would make sense to make that one your main repository, however this will be harder to manage properly
4. Your local clone should add both repositories as remotes, and you should have separate local branches tracking branches on one of the two repositories, for example `master-open` tracks `open-foobar/master`, while `master-enterprise` tracks `enterprise-foobar/master`
5. You commit new open stuff in the `master-open` branch, which you push to the open repository
6. You merge `master-open` into `master-enterprise`, meaning that you include all the commits from the open repository in the private one
7. You commit new private stuff in the `master-enterprise` branch, which you push to the open repository, making sure that you don't accidentally merge these commits into the `master-open` branch.
8. When you want to include private commits into the open version, you can use `git cherry-pick <commit-id>` to just copy commits without exposing the fact that it comes from the private fork

This workflow is heavily centered on git, but it can be easily adapted to any other SCM system.

For the second part, by default patches from people that aren't paid by you under a contract that explicitly grants you all the copyright on the created code will keep the copyright to the original author of the code. This means that unless they grant you a license to the code, you can't include it in your private fork. Normally, that doesn't even grant you a license to include it in the open source project either, unless somehow mentioned in the license of the project, or in the patch submission process (*by clicking the submit button you grant a license...*). The Apache license is good here since it explicitly mentions that patches *submitted* to the project are automatically licensed so that they can be included in the code. I haven't read the zlib license, so I can't say if it has a similar clause or not; if it doesn't be sure to include some text that requires users to agree that they grant you the right to include any patch submission into the open source project under the project's license.

If you also want to include submitted patches into your private project, then you **must** ask for a copyright license on the code *for inclusion in any private derivative of their code*. See [Wikipedia's article on CLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributor_License_Agreement) for more details and some examples. You could take a look at [Project Harmony](http://harmonyagreements.org/) for some "standard" CLAs.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache group and others require code submitters to "sign" away ownership of any changes. You would need to do the same. Before you accept fixes or enhancements they have to sign the code over.